# transforms for laser

Tags: laser, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently wrote a ROS node for an older hokuyo laser.  I wrote my own node because my laser is older and uses a protocol that is not supported by the hokuyo_node ROS package.  My node is successfully publishing laserscan messages and I would like to view the laser scans in RViz.  I'm having a problem viewing the data in RViz.  The error I get is: Transform [sender=/hokuyo_pub]
For frame [robot_pose_ekf/odom]: Frame [robot_pose_ekf/odom] does not exist

I think the problem involves transforms.  I had to specify a frameid in the header of my laserscan message.  I wasn't sure what to put here but tried: robot_pose_ekf/odom.  I am using turtlebot.

Thanks for any advice!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40237/transforms-for-laser/) by [Brad](https://answers.ros.org/users/2761/brad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2012-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ideally, I would suggest that you write a transform publisher for your laser scanner using the [tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Introduction%20to%20tf) located in the `tf` package. You must publish the laser scan data in a frame that exists on your Turtlebot. If you don't know what these frames are,  you can use the following to see all of the transforms published on your robot:

```
rosrun tf view_frames
```

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2